# Where is "My Tasks" page on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

On-premise and possibly at the beginning of SharePoint 2013, the user profile's page was looking like this (see image below) and there is the page called 'My Tasks' where you can click and see all the consolidated tasks from the projects sites that you have access to (and Outlook as well)?

[image: Figure 1]

My organisation had moved from on-premise to SharePoint Online, and the constant roll-out of new features for Microsoft has updated the User Profile so much, it is definitely looking different from the old UI now.
[image]

My question is... does anyone know ***where*** I can find the '***My Tasks***' page on **SharePoint Online**'s User Profile page? Has it been moved away? Or it's coming back? Or is there any way that I can bring it back? What should I click?

I've been exploring and hunting for it for quite some times now.. not sure if I missed it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature has been deprecated, it is described in the following article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2998445

There is a proposed workaround in the link but that solution is not fully compatible with the new "my profile" page in Delve (if it works at all nowadays)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft removed this feature and a lot of people are looking for an equivalent solution to get all his own tasks displayed on one page.
I have found a Solution, which rolls up all tasks within the current SiteCollection or multiple SiteCollection in Realtime.
It takes a couple seconds for 25'000 Items, but if there are filter set, i.E. "assigned to me", it is much faster and works well for me.
The Webpart could also be tested, I gave it a shot:
http://www.bitalus.com/index.php/Task-rollup-webpart/

Also the support is fantastic!